What are these infinite sums of powers of integers, $n^p$, multiplying a quadratic in the Bessel function $J_n(nx)$ and its derivative $J'_n(nx)$?
What are explicit elementary functions of real $x$, for $0 < x < 1$, if they exist, for $p=1$ and $p=3$ of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p [J_n(nx)]^2$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{p+1}J_n(nx)J'_n(nx)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^p [J'_n(nx)]^2$$
where $J_n(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind, and $J'_n(z)$ is its derivative with respect to its argument, $z = nx$.
P.C. Peters and J. Mathews, Physical Review 131, 435-440 (1963), Appendix, showed how to get these sums for even $p=2$ and $p=4$, but I don't see how to use their procedure for odd values of the exponent $p$.

Does their result have anything to do with $\sum_n 1/n^p$ being expressible for even $p$ and not odd $p$?
